# Binding XPath Within Binding

Tags: xml, wpf, xaml, xpath, binding

I have been searching and searching and trying multiple things and just have not been able to figure it out.  It seems like this should be straight-forward but I am at a loss.  I'm trying to pull the data based on the value from another textbox.

The basic XML that it pulls:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Translations>
  <Translation Id="Greeting">
    <English>Hello</English>
    <French>Bonjour</French>
</Translation>
```

The XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <XmlDataProvider x:Key="TranslationData" Source="F:\Translations.xml" XPath="Translations"/>
</Window.Resources>

<TextBox Name="LanguageTextBox" Text="English" Width="200" />
<TextBox Name="Results" Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource TranslationData}, XPath=*[@Id\=\'Greeting\']/English}" Width="200" />
```

I'm trying to replace the word 'English' in the XPath statement so that it uses the value of the `LanguageTextBox`, so as-is, with it being 'English' it would stay the same, but when changed to 'French', the XPath would then be the following:

```
{Binding Source={StaticResource TranslationData}, XPath=*[@Id\=\'Greeting\']/French}
```

Comment: Hi Rob, it is not working the way u think. In my experience there must at least be a trigger on LanguageTextBox.Text to pull this of. Or even better make it a ComboBox with your xml as datacource. That way u can bind Results.Text to LanguageTextBox.selecteditem greeting.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Dom, I'll research into that, new to this, so that is super helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: This seems to go into the right direction https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-bind-to-a-collection-and-display-information-based-on-selection?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 0):

If you want to directly bind to an XML document you would have to use a converter. Alternatively deserialize the XML document to a class.

Because the binding result is based on two inputs (XML document and user input) you would have to use a `MultiBinding`:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
  <XmlDataProvider x:Key="TranslationData" 
                   Source="F:\Translations.xml" 
                   XPath="Translations" />
</Window.Resources>

<TextBox x:Name="LanguageTextBox" 
         Text="English" />
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.Text>
    <MultiBinding Mode="OneWay">
      <MultiBinding.Converter>
        <local:XmlDocumentToElementInnerTextConverter />
      </MultiBinding.Converter>

      <Binding ElementName="LanguageTextBox"
               Path="Text" />
      <Binding Source="{StaticResource TranslationData}" />
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

```cs
public class XmlDocumentToElementInnerTextConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    if (values.OfType<IList>().FirstOrDefault() is IList nodeList)
    {
      XmlElement? xmlRootElement = nodeList
        .OfType<XmlElement>()
        .FirstOrDefault();
      if (xmlRootElement is not null
        && values.OfType<string>().FirstOrDefault() is string languageInput)
      {
        // Enforce capital first char to match XML tag convention
        string normalizedLanguageInput = $"{languageInput[0].ToString().ToUpper()}{languageInput[1..]}";

        XmlNodeList matchingNodes = xmlRootElement.GetElementsByTagName(normalizedLanguageInput);
        return matchingNodes?.OfType<XmlElement>().FirstOrDefault()?.InnerText
          ?? string.Empty;
      }
    }

    return string.Empty;
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
    => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

---

The following example shows how to extract an XML object based on a user selected attribute value (`Translation.Id`).
The `Id` of a `Translation` XML object maps to a translation category (the actual attribute value) which is presented to the user using a `ComboBox`.
The language is also presented to the user using a `ComboBox`.
Based on the selected value, we extract the proper translation of the selected category (e.g. `Greeting`) and language (e.g. `English`).

This example uses [LINQ to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/linq-xml-overview) instead of the `XmlDataProvider` for the improved convenience in order to traverse the XML document tree:

**Translations.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Translations>
  <Translation Id="Greeting">
    <English>Hello</English>
    <French>Bonjour</French>
  </Translation>
  <Translation Id="Goodbye">
    <English>Goodbye</English>
    <French>Au revoir</French>
  </Translation>
</Translations>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="CategorySelector"
              SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged" />
    <ComboBox x:Name="LanguageSelector"
              SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged" />
    <TextBlock Name="TranslatedValue" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  private XElement XmlDocument { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    // Load the XML document into memory
    this.XmlDocument = XElement.Load("f:/translations.xml");

    // Populate the category picker ComboBox 
    // with all categories found in the XML (Id values)
    this.CategorySelector.ItemsSource = this.XmlDocument
      .Descendants("Translation")
      .Select(translationNode => translationNode.Attribute("Id"))
      .Select(translationNodeAttribute => translationNodeAttribute.Value);

    // Populate the language picker ComboBox 
    // with all languages found in the XML
    this.LanguageSelector.ItemsSource = this.XmlDocument
      .Descendants("Translation")
      .SelectMany(translationNode => translationNode.Elements())
      .Select(languageNodes => languageNodes.Name.ToString())
      .Distinct();

    // Preselect a default category value 
    this.CategorySelector.SelectedIndex = 0;

    // Preselect a language value
    this.LanguageSelector.SelectedIndex = 0;
  }

  // Extract the new translation value from the XML document
  // when the category or language ComboBox has a new selection
  private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    SelectCurrentTranslation(this.CategorySelector.SelectedItem as string, this.LanguageSelector.SelectedItem as string);
  }

  // Extract the translated value based on category and language
  private void SelectCurrentTranslation(string? category, string? language)
  {
    if (category is null || language is null)
    {
      return;
    }

    var translatedValue = this.XmlDocument
      .Descendants("Translation")
      .First(translationNode => translationNode.Attribute("Id").Value.Equals(category, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
      .Elements()
      .First(languageNode => languageNode.Name.ToString().Equals(language, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
      .Value;

    // Display the translation in teh TextBlock
    this.TranslatedValue.Text = translatedValue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @BionicCode!  This is way above my skill-set so I appreciate it.  So the only thing I *think* I need to do here then is try to add third binding for what I want that textbox to be, so if I want it to use the Translation Id 'Greeting', or Translation Id 'Goodbye'.  Correct?

Comment: I have updated my answer to give you an example that shows how to allow the user to select an ID and language and then extarct the corresponding translated value from the XML document. The ComboBoxes are populated dynamically. Adding new IDs or languages to the XML document doesn't not require to modify the code.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is super helpful.  I'm rethinking how I was trying to implement it with your comments.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

### Underlying Issue

In your example you have got a varying *XPath* query depending on the selected language. This requires a binding on the `XPath` property, too, to react to the changing value in the language selection `TextBox` in order to create a new *XPath*. However, this is impossible, because the `XPath` property in the `Binding` type is not a [dependency property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/dependency-properties-overview?view=netdesktop-7.0), but a plain CLR property, so it does not support data binding.

> **A dependency property can reference a value through data binding**. Data binding works through a specific markup extension syntax in XAML, or the Binding object in code. With data binding, determination of the final property value is deferred until run time, at which time the value is obtained from a data source.

### A Value Converter Solution

Instead of using an *XPath* in a binding, you could use a [value converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-convert-bound-data?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) that uses your `XmlDataProvider` to retrieve texts for a *language* and a *key*. You could alternatively load the `XmlDocument` directly without the need for the data provider. Both support querying via *XPath*.

You could either write a regular `IValueConverter` or an `IMultiValueConverter` (supports binding more than one value). Since your key seems to be hardcoded anyway, I will provide the simpler regular variant, where the key can be provided as non-bindable converter parameter.

```
public class TranslateConverter : IValueConverter
{
   private XmlDataProvider _dataProvider;

   public XmlDataProvider DataProvider
   {
      get => _dataProvider;
      set
      {
         _dataProvider = value;
         ForceLoadXmlDocument();
      }
   }

   public string FallbackText { get; set; }

   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      if (DataProvider is null)
         throw new InvalidOperationException("No XML data provider set.");

      if (DataProvider.Document is null)
         throw new InvalidOperationException("No XML document loaded.");

      if (!(value is string language) || !(parameter is string key))
         return Binding.DoNothing;

      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(language) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(key))
         return FallbackText;

      return SelectLanguageText(language, key) ?? FallbackText;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
   }

   private void ForceLoadXmlDocument()
   {
      if (_dataProvider == null || _dataProvider.Document != null)
         return;

      _dataProvider.IsInitialLoadEnabled = true;
      _dataProvider.IsAsynchronous = false;
      _dataProvider.Refresh();
   }

   private string SelectLanguageText(string language, string key)
   {
      var xpath = $"//*[@Id='{key}']/{language}";
      return DataProvider.Document.SelectSingleNode(xpath)?.InnerText;
   }
}
```

Most of the code consists of checks that the arguments are valid. In the core `SelectLanguageText` method, the text from the data provider is queried using *XPath* just like in XAML. If there is no translation, a fallback text is returned. The `ForceLoadXmlDocument` method is used as a [workaround](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3a2effe7-c4df-4b5a-8084-db76a9d667d3/access-xmldocument-in-xmldataprovider-return-null?forum=wpf), since the XML document might not be immediately loaded by the data provider.

In XAML, you would define an instance of the converter and use it in the binding.

```
<Window.Resources>
   <XmlDataProvider x:Key="TranslationData" Source="/Translations.xml" XPath="Translations"/>
   <local:TranslateConverter x:Key="TranslateConverter" DataProvider="{StaticResource TranslationData}" FallbackText="# No translation found! #"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

```
<TextBox Name="LanguageTextBox" Text="English" Width="200" />
<TextBox Name="Results" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=LanguageTextBox, Converter={StaticResource TranslateConverter}, ConverterParameter=Greeting}" Width="200"/>
```

### An Alternative Solution

You could create a dedicated tranlation provider type that exposes a property `Language` that is set through a binding, like in your example with the `TextBox`.

```
<TextBox Name="LanguageTextBox" Text="{Binding Language, Source={StaticResource TranslationProvider}}" />
```

Then you can expose an [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/). that can be bound with the key for translation.

```
<TextBox Name="LanguageTextBox" Text="{Binding [Greeting], Source={StaticResource TranslationProvider}}" />
```

The logic would be very similar to the converter using a data provider or XML document directly.

### Remarks

- Using a `TextBox` to input the language is not recommended. It allows for any value and needs additional validation (see the null or whitespace checks in the converter). You should rather use a `ComboBox` or any other control that provides only the distinct, valid values to choose from.
- It seems odd to me how your translation file is structured. You provide a translation element for a key, that contains values for each language. You would rather have an element for a language with translations for each key. This enables you to ship language files independently.
- If the language file is not local, put it in the application resources, otherwise will get redundant instances of the same dictionary in each window.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is super helpful.  I'm rethinking how I was trying to implement it with your comments.  Thanks again!